# Сompletion playlist and resetting index in just_audio

Tags: flutter, playlist, just-audio

I'm using the **just_audio** package, I have a playlist, and after playing all the tracks, the current index remains equal to the index of the last track. Is there a way to make the index equal to **0** when the playlist ends?

```
final myPlayList = ConcatenatingAudioSource(
  children: listAudios,
);
await _player.setAudioSource(myPlayList, initialIndex: 0, preload: false);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Listen for the `completed` state and seek to index `0`. Assuming you also want to stop playing at that point, call `pause()` too:

```dart
_player.processingStateStream.listen((state) async {
  if (state == ProcessingState.completed) {
    await _player.pause();
    await _player.seek(Duration.zero, index: 0);
  }
});
```

Regarding the call to `pause()`: just_audio state is a composite of `playing` and `processingState` and you will only hear audio when `playing=true, processingState=ready` which is what you have during normal playback. The `playing` state only ever changes when you tell it to change, but the `processingState` may change independently depending on what is happening in the audio.

When reaching the end of the playlist, it will transition to `playing=true, processingState=completed`, hence no audio. If you seek back to the beginning, it will be `playing=true, processingState=ready` so you'll hear the audio automatically start back up. This may surprise you, but think of it as comparable to what happens in a YouTube video after it completes, but if you seek to the beginning it continues playing (because it's now ready, not completed).

If you want it to stop playing, you need to actually set `playing=false` with either `pause()` or `stop()`, where the former keeps things in memory, and the latter releases all resources.

For more information about the state model and its rationale, see [The State Model](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio#the-state-model) section of the README.

Comment: In this case, the playlist is played over and over again. **UPD** worked as `player.stop()` added. Could you fix the library so that the player has this behavior out of the box?

Comment: The library is working as intended, you can read the README section on how the state model works, but I have also updated my answer to explain it.